# Struts 2 jquery grid Edit dialog box issues

Tags: jquery, struts2, struts2-jquery, struts2-jquery-grid, struts2-jquery-plugin

I am facing one issue in Struts2 jquery grid plugin:

- if I click on <kbd>add</kbd> navigator button on grid panel the `add` dialog box is opening perfectly fine but after clicking on <kbd>add</kbd> when I clicked to <kbd>edit</kbd> button... the same `add` dialog box is opening again.
- If click <kbd>edit</kbd> button first then `edit` dialog box is opening and after <kbd>edit</kbd> button click if I click on <kbd>add</kbd> then same `edit` dialog is opening.

Why are <kbd>edit</kbd> / <kbd>add</kbd>  not getting refreshed ?

Below is my code:

```xml
<sjg:grid gridview="true"
        id="gridtable"
        caption="MAN TIMESHEET MANAGEMENT"
        dataType="json"
        href="%{remoteurl}"
        editurl="%{editurl}"

        pager="true"
        navigator="true"
        navigatorEdit="true"
        navigatorAdd="true"
        navigatorDelete="true"
        gridModel="gridModel"   

        navigatorAddOptions="{height:280, width:500 ,reloadAfterSubmit:true}"
        navigatorEditOptions="{height:280, width:800 ,reloadAfterSubmit:true}"     
        navigatorDeleteOptions="{height:280,width:500, reloadAfterSubmit:true}"        
        rowList="10,15,20"
        rowNum="15"
        rownumbers="true"
        width="999"
        multiselect="true"
        resizable="true" 
        viewrecords="true"  
        onSelectRowTopics="rowselect"        
        name="gridModel" 
        loadonce="true" />
```

Comment: I am facing this issue from past 2 days. Done alot of googling but could not find solution

Comment: Which version of the plugin? Any js errors in console? Try with `editinline` attribute set to `true`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I found cause of issue ..it was  cache issue..when i cleared my browser cache it's working fine now.

Comment: Now i facing a small issue in next and previous button.. Next button is not loading the next records ..its just show only first 15 records..